# Is there a way to play H264 video stream in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, h.264, picamera

I want to play H264 video stream(raspberry pi's camera) at my flutter application(Android) via Bluetooth, now I can read and transfer h264 compressed data use `picamera` in Python, but I haven't any ideas to show it in Flutter, I'm not familiar with video encoding.

I want to know how I can do. Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I'm exactly in the same stage now. Finding a way to play h264 stream from a picamera but over wifi

Comment: @Xmindz I had tried to transfer video frame by binary with bluetooth tcp connection,but the frame is incomplete and FPS must be very little.Seems that bluetooth's bandwidth is too small that can't transfer a high quality video stream.